# In $|x_1,...,x_n\rangle$, can the individual constituents be called qubits?

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, interpretations

> A qubit is a quantum system in which the Boolean states 0 and 1 are
> rep- resented by a prescribed pair of normalised and mutually
> orthogonal quantum states labeled as ${|0⟩, |1⟩}$

According to [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0011013.pdf). Then a quantum register $\mid x_1x_2...x_n\rangle, x_i\in\{0,1\}$ is defined to be collection of n qubits.

Now I often see expressions like $\mid x_1, ... x_n \rangle$ where the $x_i$ belong to some $S \subset \mathbf{Z}$.

1. Can the individual constituents $\mid x_i \rangle$ be called qubits even though they are non-binary?
2. Would it be appropriate to call $\mid x_1, ... x_n \rangle$ a qubit register in this case?
3. What is the physical interpretation of such a register?

Comment: I think qubits are binary by definition, but there may be another to represent them I don't know of.

Comment: *"Now I often see..."* -- Where?

Comment: please remember that each post should contain a single, focused question

Answer (score 3):

The $|x_i\rangle$ you mention here are **qudits**, they are the generalization of qubits to base $d$ with $|S| = d$. It is categorized by a superposition of $d$ states, same way a qubit is described by the superposition of 2 states.
In base 3 it has a specific name as well, this is called **qutrit**.

Comment: I see that it is a generalization in syntax, but what does it mean? What's the physical meaning of $\mid -12\rangle$?

Comment: Also how can you consider the basis vector $\mid 0 \rangle$ to be a superposition of two states? Which two?

Comment: @gen: First question: -12 is not natural number, hence it cannot appear in your definition. Second question: in $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ basis any qubit can be writen as $|q\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$. So, $|0\rangle$ is superposition where $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 0$. This seems strange but the qubit is considered to be in superposition until it is measured. In this case, zero is always returned.

Comment: @MartinVesely thanks for your comment. First question: Yes, the definition was mistyped. I meant to write $S \subset \mathbf{Z}$. So I'm still interested what $\mid -12 \rangle$ means. Second: That's fair enough I guess.